# c# multiple application instances connected to only one USB serial device

Tags: windows-xp, serial-port, usb

This is a completely new one by me and I'll appreciate any and all advice. I was given a last minute feature requirement that MUST allow multiple instances of our core application to talk to one, and only one, USB Serial Port device (We use a Point-Of-Sale credit card reader/signature capture POS SigCap device.)

Can anyone please explain how this might be handled in C#? We currently use **Ingenico dlls** to communicate to the device and opening a second application will cause the POS SigCap to fail to open due to the conflict, both on the line and on the device itself.

I don't believe that this is possible due to the nature of serial port hardware on **Windows XP** machines but your input is valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cant connect multiple times to a serial port!

but you could make a "server" that handles that. so you have a single application that connects to the serial port and communicates with it, and the other applications communicate with that "server". this might cause some bugs though, depending on how exactly the device works.

i think thats the only way.

Edit:
I just searched a bit and found this software which does something like that:
http://www.eltima.com/products/serialsplitter/
maybe that can help you

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess I don't understand what you mean by a server. Would that involve sending the data through a network to "serial port managing" computer. That application looks like it would be very good for specific designs, I do not think the DLLs I am using will allow multiple connections to multiple serial ports. The configuration tools the vendor supplied let me set only one serial port.

Comment: You dont have to use network necessarily. You could use windows messaging too. But thats a bit dirty. I would recommend a local tcp server application that provides the functions of the dll to multiple clients